Request Header is undefined
I need some help.
I want to get the token from localStorage, but some how it doesn't work.
It happens when the page moves to dynamic route page.
Using Next.js,JavaScript,Supabase,Express,Prisma
api/middlewares/isAuthenticated.js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  console.log("request header is", req.headers.authorization);  // <-- Somehow this is undefined when go to dynamic route

  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
  console.log("token is ", token);

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "error" });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err");
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "error" });
    }

    req.userId = decoded?.id;
        next();
  });
}

module.exports = isAuthenticated;

/api/routers/users.js
const router = require("express").Router();
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");
const isAuthenticated = require("../middlewares/isAuthenticated");

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

router.get("/find", isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: req.userId } });

    if (!user) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: "not found" });
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      user: { id: user.id, email: user.email, username: user.username },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

router.get("/profile/:userId", isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;

  try {
    const profile = await prisma.profile.findUnique({
      where: {
        userId: parseInt(userId),
      },
      include: {
        user: {
          include: {
            profile: true,
          },
        },
      },
    });
    if (!profile) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ message: "cannot find profile" });
    }

    res.status(200).json(profile);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error.message);
  }
});

module.exports = router;

The endpoint "users/find" can get token,but "users/profile/:userId" cannot get token.
The endpoint's name is correct.
I want to get token from below.
/client/context/auth.js
"use client";
import React, { ReactNode, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import apiClient from "../lib/apiClient";


type AuthContextTypes = {
  user: null | { id: number; username: string; email: string };
  login: (token: string) => void;
  logout: () => void;
};

type AuthProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

const AuthContext = React.createContext<AuthContextTypes>({
  user: null,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {},
});

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: AuthProviderProps) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<null | {
    id: number;
    email: string;
    username: string;
  }>(null);

 
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");

    console.log("Token from localStorage:", token); 
    if (token) {

      apiClient.defaults.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
       apiClient
        .get("/users/find")
        .then((res) => {
          setUser(res.data.user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("User authentication failed:", error);
          // Optional: You can handle the error here (e.g., clear the token, show an alert, etc.)
        });
    }
  }, []);

  const login = (token: string) => {
    localStorage.setItem("auth_token", token);
    apiClient.defaults.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;

    try {
      apiClient.get("/users/find").then((res) => {
        setUser(res.data.user);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      window.alert(error);
    }
  }; // Closing bracket added here

  const logout = () => {
    console.log("I am deleteing the header");
    localStorage.removeItem("auth_token");
    delete apiClient.defaults.headers["Authorization"];
    setUser(null); // Clear the user state on logout
  };

  const value = {
    user,
    login,
    logout,
  };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};


I tought the jsonwebtoken is stored in cookies not localStorage.

I just looked at your code carefully and it seems like you are adding the token to the request header every time, which is not a best practice. So in some cases you can get the token from isAuthenticated, but can't get in other cases.
I think you should use an interceptor from axios to set the token for all API calls.
Below is a sample code.
import axios from 'axios';
const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, // Ajust your backend url
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    }
});

api.interceptors.request.use((config: any) => {
    const token = window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken') ?? null; // Get token from localStroage and set here

    return {
        ...config,
        headers: {
            ...config.headers,
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    };
});

api.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response,
    (error) => Promise.reject((error.response && error.response.data) || 'Wrong Services')
);

export default apiClient;

By updating apiClient you can always get Bearer token from isAuthenticated middleware.
